# How do I get to the value of key "/" in JSON props object

Tags: javascript, json

In my nextjs project, I'm using _app.js to pass props to a page. I am able to get the data I want, but I'm not sure how I can get the value of the key, "/".

This is my JSON data

```
{
  "router": {
    "pathname": "/",
    "route": "/",
    "query": {},
    "asPath": "/",
    "components": {
      "/": {
        "props": {
          "somedata": [
              ... some data
          ]
        }
      },
      "/_app": {}
    },
    "isFallback": false,
    "events": {}
  }
}
```

I have no problem getting down to router.components, but how do I get to router.components./, which isn't allowed. Thank you for any help.

Comment: obj.router.components['/']

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just access the properties using dots and get the '/' sign/key with squared brackets.

```js
const obj={
  "router": {
    "pathname": "/",
    "route": "/",
    "query": {},
    "asPath": "/",
    "components": {
      "/": {
        "props": {
          "somedata": [
             
          ]
        }
      },
      "/_app": {}
    },
    "isFallback": false,
    "events": {}
  }
}

console.log(obj.router.components['/'])
```